# Spaces in TFS file path for Command Line

Tags: tfs

I am running a batch script that automates some calls to `tf.exe` and have run into an issue when I have spaces in my path name. For example if get the following at the command prompt:

```
>tf history /noprompt "$/MyProject/_source_xlf/Some Dir With Spaces/some file w spaces.xlf"

No history entries were found for the item and version combination specified.
```

***Note the double quotes in the command***. In the *Source Explorer* in VS2012 I can navigate to the file just fine, and view the history with no issues through the GUI. Some of the GUI operations even display the server path of the file, which I can copy and paste directly into the `tf` command (which is how I verify the file path is correct).

I've read elsewhere that tfs supports spaces in the path, and well it does in the GUI, so is there some trick to making it work at the command prompt?

Comment: Are you running this command in a working directory that is part of a workspace folder mapping connected to the correct TFS server? Your scenario works fine on my machine, so I doubt the problem is with the spaces.

Comment: I am not running it in the working directory, however I am able to successfully run it on every other file that does not contain spaces in the path from an unrelated directory. That being said, I will attempt to run the command from the mapped working directory to see if that makes a difference though.

Comment: OK... so clearly I was doing something stupid... because it now seems to be working. Thanks @moerketh for the sanity check